# jquery sorting table

Tags: jquery

I have this table

```
<table>
    <th>
        Food Name
    </th>
    <th>
        Restaurant Name
    </th>
    <?php
    if ($isCustomer == "1") {
        ?>
        <th>

        </th><?php
}
    ?>
    <?php while ($row = $allFoods->fetch()) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['foodName']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['restaurantName']; ?>
            </td>
            <?php
            if ($isCustomer == "1") {
                ?>
                <td class="favoriteRow">
                    <a class="link" href="<?php echo URL . 'customer/addFavoriteFood/' . $row['foodID'] ?>">  Add Favorite</a>
                </td>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

I tried to sort it a lot, but i couldn't, it seems like i have to reload the page with the already sorted items, but i need to sort it using jquery, any help will be appreciated

Comment: (this is a joke) Try Stacksort :-) http://gkoberger.github.com/stacksort/

Comment: use: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: you can also use https://github.com/ozzyogkush/jquery.sortableTable

Comment: why do you need `jquery` to sort on client side while you can sort your things at server side in `php`

Comment: sometimes the user may want to sort the data based on other fields or displayed information, and its easier and quicker to just sort it on the page than send requests to the server and have to wait for a response. less resource intensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeed with [jquery tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/), it's very simple way to sort html tables.

code sample as below,

html:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>Jason</td> 
    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td> 
    <td>$100.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Conway</td> 
    <td>Tim</td> 
    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use my sortableTable plugin at https://github.com/ozzyogkush/jquery.sortableTable . It's pretty easy to use, and very extensible.